# How do I stop newline from scanf being input into a char array that's filled immediately after the scanf input?

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I'm working on a piece of code and while checking it for errors I have found that for some reason `\n` is input into the first position in the char array named `num` in `main()`. It's related to `scanf` because when I comment it out, it works as it should. I could use `isdigit` and `isalpha`, but that doesn't seem to be a particularly efficient solution. How can I prevent the newline from being input into the char array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define LEN 10000

int expon(int expBase, int power){
    unsigned int i=1;
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<power; j++) i*=expBase;
    return i;
}
void convToNums(char* num, int* numI, int length){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<length; i++){
        if(isdigit(num[i])) numI[i]=num[i]-'0';
        if(isalpha(num[i])) numI[i]=num[i]-'A'+10;
    }
}

void convert(char* num, int base1, int base2, int length){
    int numI[LEN];
    int i;
    convToNums(num, numI, length);
    for(i=0; i<length; i++) printf("%d", numI[i]);
    printf("\n");

}

int getNum(char *num){
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while((c=fgetc(stdin)) != ' '){
        num[i]=c;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(){
    char num[LEN];
    int n, base1, base2, length;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        length=getNum(num);
        scanf("%d %d", &base1, &base2);
        convert(num, base1, base2, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%d", &n);` stops when it sees a non-digit character after the digits it reads, so it stops when it sees the newline character and leaves that character in the buffer.

Remove it yourself:

```
// Get the next character to see what it is.
int c = getchar();

// If there is another character and it is not newline, put it back.
if (c != EOF && c != '\n')
    ungetc(c, stdin);
```